# How does UdpClient checksum works

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, udp

I use the `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient` class as the base layer of my communication system between my game client, server and API therefore I need to be sure that received data has not been corrupted. And as [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation) it is specified that checksum controlling is included in the UDP protocol.

Yet, when I try to test that with Clumsy with the following settings:[image]

My client sends:
`00-09-00-00-00-00-00-01-05-00-00-00-32-39-30-30-36-05-93-34-E6-BF-05-92-E9-5B-3E-01-00-01-00-01-00 ActorUpdateRequestPacket [Character]`
Thus the server receives this malformed packet:
`00-09-00-00-00-00-00-01-05-00-00-00-37-34-30-38-9F-50-58-D9-9B-80-1A-BD-37-F6-BF-01-00-05-6F-9C-F2-BE-05-61-6F-61-3F`

No error is thrown (apart if I try to deserialize obviously) nothing happens and I don't know why as the checksum should not match the received data hence UdpClient should at least silently discard the packet.
If I want to guarantee my data integrity then I would be forced to write another algorithm on top of the supposedly existing one.

What am I missing ?
Thanks.

**[EDIT]**
As Ron pointed out checksum coverage is only optional in IPv4 so I guess it's disabled by default.
However I can't figure out how to enable it, I tried `SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.ChecksumCoverage, 1)` but it keeps throwing `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied` error with any kind of argument (bool, int, empty byte array, null).. I've looked on the internet but I don't found anything, if anybody knows please tell me :)

Comment: The UDP checksum is _optional_ for IPv4, but _required_ for IPv6.

Comment: @RonMaupin You're right, still I can't find how to enable it.. :/